# Safe use of ctypes.create_string_buffer?

Tags: python, ctypes

Usually in Python when you do an assignment of a variable, you don't get a copy - you just get a second reference to the same object.

```
a = b'Hi'
b = a
a is b  # shows True
```

Now when you use `ctypes.create_string_buffer` to get a buffer to e.g. interact with a Windows API function, you can use the `.raw` attribute to access the bytes.  But what if you want to access those bytes after you've deleted the buffer?

```
c = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'Hi')
d = c.raw
e = c.raw
d is e  # shows False?
d == e  # shows True as you'd expect
c.raw is c.raw  # shows False!
del c
```

At this point are `d` and `e` still safe to use?  From my experimentation it looks like the `.raw` attribute makes *copies* when you access it, but I can't find anything in the official documentation to support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.raw` returns a separate, immutable Python `bytes` object each time called it *may* be an interned version (`d is e` *could* return `True`) but is safe to use.

An easy test:

```py
>>> x=ctypes.create_string_buffer(1)
>>> a = x.raw
>>> x[0] = 255
>>> b = x.raw
>>> a
b'\x00'
>>> b
b'\xff'
```

[This point](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#surprises) in the documentation comments on this for the `ctypes` type `c_char_p`, but it applies to other `ctypes` types like `c_char_Array` as well (emphasis mine):

```
>>> s = c_char_p()
>>> s.value = b"abc def ghi"
>>> s.value
b'abc def ghi'
>>> s.value is s.value
False
```

> ...
> Why is it printing `False`? `ctypes` instances are objects containing a memory block plus some descriptors accessing the contents of the memory. Storing a Python object in the memory block does not store the object itself, instead the `contents` of the object is stored. **Accessing the contents again constructs a new Python object each time!**

Comment: Thanks, I never thought to check the docs of other functions but it makes sense that they would work the same way. Also makes sense that they would build a new object each time, since the resource they're wrapping isn't a Python object.